# add something to an array based on order

Tags: java, junit

I have a method that adds an object to an array but it adds it based on order. So lets say I have an array that has an apples, and cola. If I wanted to add a banana it would go between those two objects. But I keep getting errors when I run my jUnit tests. Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Adds an item to the list.  This method assumes that the list is already
 * sorted in alphabetical order based on the names of the items in the list.
 * 
 * The new item will be inserted into the list in the appropriate place so
 * that the list will remain alphabetized by names.
 * 
 * In order to accomodate the new item, the internal array must be re-sized 
 * so that it is one unit larger than it was before the call to this method.
 *  
 * @param itemToAdd refers to a Listable item to be added to this list
 */

public void add(Listable itemToAdd) {

    int i;
    Listable[] newItems = new Listable[items.length+1];
    for(i=0; i<items.length;i++){
        if(items[i].getName().compareTo(itemToAdd.getName()) < 0){
            newItems[i] = items[i];
        }   else{
            break;
        }
    }
    int str=i;
    for(i=str+1;i<items.length;i++){
        newItems[i+1] = items[i];
    }
    newItems[str] = itemToAdd;
}
```

I keep getting an error that states that the test expected <14> but got <0> so now I think that means its my constructor thats the problem:

```
/**
 * This constructor creates an empty list by creating an internal array
 * of size 0.  (Note that this is NOT the same thing as setting the internal
 * instance variable to null.) 
 */
public SortedListOfImmutables() {
    int i = 0;
    items = new Listable[0];

    //orders the list
    for( i=0;i<items.length;i++){
        if(Food.FOOD_OBJECTS[i].getName().compareTo(Food.FOOD_OBJECTS[i+1].getName()) < 0){
            items[i] = Food.FOOD_OBJECTS[i];
        }else{
            items[i+1] = Food.FOOD_OBJECTS[i];
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you also post your junit here? Also I'm curious about the `items` being an empty array with size zero and we add something to it in the loop. Am I missing something?

Comment: And why does the test expect "14"? Which test, what does it do? You make it very hard to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think atleast one of your problems is with this for loop:

```
 for(i=str+1;i<items.length;i++){
    newItems[i+1] = items[i];
}
```

I'll just use an example list to show you why. Lets say our items list contains {apple, banana, orange, pineapple}. Then we want to insert "grape" which should be inserted between "banana" and "orange". The first for loop does does 3 iterations before breaking (putting "apple" and "banana" into newItems, then breaks on i=2) You assign str = 2 which is the index "grape" should be inserted. But then when inserting the remaining elements, you set i=str+1 which would be 3 in this case, so

```
newItems[i+1] = items[i];
```

would put "pineapple" into index 4 of newItems, which is correct but you completely skip putting what is in index 2 in items ("orange") into the newItems at index 3.
To fix this, you either want to do:

```
 for(i=str;i<items.length;i++){
    newItems[i+1] = items[i];
}
```

or:

```
 for(i=str+1;i<items.length;i++){
    newItems[i] = items[i-1];
}
```

Comment: You're right it worked it was my loop that was the problem